# Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[23000]:

Tags: php, pdo

Can anyone help with this please?

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '127' for key 1 in /usr/www/users/firstiw/competitions/facebook/64ongordon/competition.php on line 33

Comment: Before you vote me out - please tell me what you mean? What information do you need? I'm not a developer - I'm trying to fix files I can access?

Comment: From that error it looks like you're either trying to update a primary key or insert a new primary key to a value that is already in the database, but without more information there's really no telling what the problem is.

Comment: @Sharon: Please do not post the same question multiple times.  To answer this question we need more info.  It says the error is on line 33 of competition.php.  Posting that line of code may help us answer this.

Comment: @Rocket @watcher thanks for your help. I'm following this up on the original string - i posted this because that one was "closed" - sorry to waste ur time!

Comment: @Sharon: If you post the code for line 33 on the other question, it can get reopened.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a record that has id=127 or some of your relationships are messed up. But i am shooting in the dark right now. You would have to provide more information about this. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi @Teodor - this was resolved, thank you. The answer needed was: the index field datatype was set up to a type of integer field that only accepts numbers up to 127, have now changed the datatype to a regular integer